# Почему неправильно работает shouldComponentUpdate после использования setState в функции?

Tags: reactjs

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

class BrandModels extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = { items : [ undefined ] }


  }


  shouldComponentUpdate( nextProps, nextState ) {

    console.log( nextState.items, this.state.items )

    if ( nextState.items != this.state.items)
      return true;

    return false;

  }

  addGroup(){

    let items = this.state.items;

    items.push( undefined );

    this.setState({ items : items })

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={country_brand_mod_list">
        
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <RaisedButton
              label={window._sharedData.loc.app.add}
              primary={true}
              onClick={this.addGroup.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default BrandModels;
```

после нажатия на кнопку добавляеться 1 елемент в массив стейта items

но, в shouldComponentUpdate nextState.items почему-то равно всегда this.state.items
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: push меняет существующий массив. Создавайте копию и добавляйте в нее новый элемент

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/1988244